# Exporting database Oracle 7.3 on Windows NT 3.51

Tags: oracle, dump

How to take dump files on Oracle7.3 running on Windows NT 3.51?

Should you stand in the Orant/bin folder and run one of the programs there like>

```
exp73 SYSTEM/password@[dbinstance] FULL=Y LOG=EXPORT.LOG
```

Did not work

[image]
These services:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, it's been about 18 years since I've been near a server like that.  Is this syntax more helpful?

EXP73.EXE USERNAME/PASSWORD@INSTANCE FILE=OUTFILE.DMP FULL=Y LOG=LOGFILE.LOG

Comment: No, you mean that is a user and pass for the db something like system or so?

Comment: Got ORA-09352: OracleService(SID) has not been started

Comment: Does this thing have a control panel / services.msc equivalent? (BTW I though the first NT version was 3.5. What's NT1?)

Comment: Yes got Contol Panel.

Comment: I'm sure even Windows NT could take proper screenshots...

Comment: In a couple of months your database software will be old enough to buy cigarettes.

Comment: Come on guys, he may be posting from his phone because the server itself doesn't have a browser new enough to use SO, or it may not have a direct path to the Internet, or scripting may be disabled by group policy, etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok here's what I did:

I was in the ORANT\BIN folder.

I had to figure out what the SID was for the DB. Did that via an Oracle client which I tried to connect remotely to Oracle on the server.

```
set oracle_sid=a

exp73.exe System/manager file=myexp13xxxx.dmp full=y log=mylog130527.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Been a long time but I remember that you can use either ORACLE_SID or LOCAL to set your database. Check your registry (something like local_machine/software/oracle). Make sure you have only one of the two set. Make sure that your database service is running. Then try to start an sql session first: sqlplus username/password. Once that works so will exp.